# How can I start a chat, if there is not a box suggesting to do it?

Tags: support, chat

If I can start a chat, just copying one or two comments "by hand" won't be a problem, but I cannot even find a way to start it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users with more than 100 reputation on a site can start new chat rooms. Go to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) (without this link reachable by clicking on the SE hamburger icon in the top right of the desktop site, where you should see the triple "help chat log out" beside the name of the SE site you're on).

In the bottom right corner you should see "create a new room" - click it to create a new chat room.

Comment: Yes, I finally found how to do it. But by that time the discussion I wanted to continue had been automatically created (too many comments). So now I have a chat room too many. How can I remove it ?

Comment: @Alfred Chat rooms that aren't used for some time will automatically get frozen and then deleted. You don't need to do anything for that.

Comment: OK, I'll just leave alone the one I created myself till it is deleted. The discussion went on in the chat room that was automatically created.